# Python program cannot be executed from console due to AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, console

`OS: Windows 10`

I have a very simple python script `datetime.py` :

```python
import datetime 
print(datetime.datetime.now())
input("press enter to continue")
```

Running from console: `python datetime.py`

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "datetime.py", line 1, in <module>
    import datetime
  File "C:\Users\DAN024\Documents\Python\datetime.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: change your file name. Using `datetime.py` will result in the `import` statement trying to read your script instead of the actual `datetime` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the name of the file from datetime.py to something else